# Add histogram axis labels in legend histogram in tmap R

Tags: r, histogram, legend, tmap

I would like to add axis labels to the legend histogram in tmap. Here is an example code:

```
library(tmap)
data(World)

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("gdp_cap_est", style = "quantile", palette = "RdYlBu",legend.hist=TRUE)
```

[image]

I am hoping to get something like this:

[image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16kzU.png)]

Sorry it seems like a very simple question but I couldn't find an answer online.

Answer (score 1):

Although tmap is not very suitable for such things here's a solution to accomplish what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(sf)
data(World)

# create label for x axis
coords <- tibble(x = -100, y = -90, label = "GDP") %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"))

# create linestring with y axis label
ls <- tibble(geometry = st_sfc(st_linestring(rbind(c(-180, -90), c(-180, -20)))), 
             label = "Frequency") %>% st_as_sf()

tm_shape(World) +
  tm_polygons("gdp_cap_est",
              style = "quantile", 
              palette = "RdYlBu",
              legend.hist = TRUE) +
  tm_shape(coords) +
  tm_text(text = "label", size = 0.75) +
  tm_shape(ls) +
  tm_lines(col = "white") + # "hide" linestring
  # need to use along.lines = T here to rotate and align the label along the defined linestring
  tm_text(text = "label", size = 0.75, along.lines = T) +
  tm_layout(legend.position = c(0.04, 0.04))
```

[image]